# Manipulation of list to create extra calculated column

Tags: c#, list, class

I have this program that reads a .txt file and creates a `List<Class>`. This class has 10 "columns". See image below

[image]

The Total UoM column is not in the .txt file but I would like to create this extra column as an additional column in my collection. So the last column in the text file is Width.

Calculation should be as follows:

For rows where Width = 0, Total UoM should be Qty * Length (Ignore Net Weight)

For rows where Width > 0, Total UoM should be Qty * Length * Width

Code thus far:

```
// Structure of SteelAssembly Class object
  public class SteelAssembly
  {
      public int LotNo { get; set; }
      public string AssemblyMark { get; set; }
      public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
      public string Part { get; set; }
      public int Quantity { get; set; }
      public string Profile { get; set; }
      public string Grade { get; set; }
      public decimal Length { get; set; }
      public decimal Weight { get; set; }
      public decimal Width { get; set; }
  }
```

...............

```
 lines = new List<string>();
                        assembly = new List<SteelAssembly>();

                        // Open the text file using a stream reader.
                        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
                        {
                            // Read the stream to a string, and write the string to the console.
                            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                                lines.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                        }

                        // Read job number
                        jobNumber = lines.FirstOrDefault();

                        // Remove job number from list
                        lines.Remove(jobNumber);
                        if (lines.Count > 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                foreach (string row in lines)
                                {
                                    // Split the columns of the .txt document
                                    string[] words = row.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                                    // Remove all null or empty rows
                                    if (words != null || words.Length != 0)
                                    {
                                        // Transform data to SteelAssembly Class object
                                        assembly.Add(new SteelAssembly
                                        {
                                            LotNo = Convert.ToInt32(words[0]),
                                            AssemblyMark = words[1].Trim(),
                                            AssemblyName = words[2].Trim(),
                                            Part = words[3].Trim(),
                                            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(words[4]),
                                            Profile = words[5].Trim(),
                                            Grade = words[6].Trim(),
                                            Length = Convert.ToDecimal(words[7]),
                                            Weight = Convert.ToDecimal(words[8]),
                                            Width = Convert.ToDecimal(words[9]),
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

....................

Each unique Assembly Mark/Lot No. will be a new production order so we have this dictionary

```
// Create dictionary         
var dictionary = assembly
                 .GroupBy(x => new
                 {
                     x.AssemblyMark,
                     x.LotNo                                   
                 })
                 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

This transforms into:

[image]

How do I manage to get the extra column in my dictionary with the correct total UoM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a `get` only property that returns a computed value based on those criteria. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
public class SteelAssembly
{
    public int LotNo { get; set; }
    public string AssemblyMark { get; set; }
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string Part { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Profile { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public decimal Length { get; set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    public decimal Width { get; set; }

    public decimal UoM 
    {
        get
        {
            return Width == 0 ? (Quantity * Length) : (Quantity * Length * Width);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the value for this property is computed only when you are reading it.

Comment: Ok. How to set this value to appear as I create the assembly list?

Comment: It will be automatically calculated as you fill in the `Width`, `Quantity` etc. Try reading it from the item once the other properties are set.

Comment: I see. This is fine.